# Azure pipeline on PR validate file before merging to master branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have master branch which has multiple yaml files. Every file on update will be pushed to feature/{filename.yaml} and with PR will be merged to master branch.

But before merging I need to validate that file from feature has valid YAML syntax.

If syntax is not valid build will fail and not be merged to master branch.

But if everything is ok I need to send content of yaml file to API endpoint, and then merge it to master branch.

Thanks

Comment: At which step did you encounter problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Files Validator task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=roshkovski.Files-Validator&ssr=false#overview) to validate file.

[[image]